# IIS URL Rewrite - need help rewriting friendly urls for a forum

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm new to using the URL Rewrite module and I'm having trouble with what I thought would be a simple URL rewrite for forum threads (using IIS 7.5)

I need to rewrite:

```
/forum/100/2534/friendly-title
```

or:

```
/forum/100/2534/334/comment/friendly-thread-title
```

to:

```
/forum/?forum=100&thread=2534&post=334&postType=comment
```

The rule that I have written (not working) is:

```
^forum/([1-9][0-9][0-9]*)/([1-9]*)/(([1-9]*)/(post|comment)/)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,50})$
```

Which maps to:

```
/forum/?forum={R:1}&thread={R:2}&post={R:4}&postType={R:5}
```

I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: I tested the regex and it does all the values, though R:4 and R:5 are NULL when I try to map the first type of friendly URL.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct that `{R:4}` and `{R:5}` are empty when you use the first URL. That's because there are no values for these fields. The RegEx still matches though so the URL will still be rewritten. Your code should properly handle empty values for the `post` and `postType` querystring parameters to display the entire thread and not just a specific comment (at least that what I assume is suppose to happen).

By the way, a more logical URL structure would be:

```
/forum/100/2534/friendly-thread-title/comment/334
```

This won't help you this this particular problem though but just on a side note.

Comment: Thanks... I thought about that URL structure but I wasn't sure if it's more SEO friendly when the title is always at the end. Do you know? And do you know what might be causing my problem?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to debug this? I've tried doing the most simple rewrite, ^forum/(100)(/?)$ -> /forum/ and I get the same result when I go to http://testing.domain.com/forum/100.

Comment: @Redtopia you can use the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)

Comment: The RegEx and the rewrite rule looks fine to me. Can you post the rewrite rules from the web.config?  Maybe there is something wrong there. Are you using existing forum software or is this something your wrote yourself?